# Go to Specific Tab on different Page link click and toggle active class

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I'm developing a web page in which I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap Framework and their Bootstrap Tabs JS. It works great but I am trying to add extra links outside the tabs panel to open the tabs, it works fine clicking the tabs link under the `ul` **`-->`** `li` links.

But  when I click a link outside the **`nav panel-tabs`** how can I have the tab panel switch and the `active` class added to the **`nav panel-tabs`**  `li` CSS class element when clicking a link outside the `nav panel` itself (as the `active` class shows a different background color in my case).

For example:

These links are outside the panel code up the page:

```
<a href="page.php#gallery">Gallery</a>
<a href="page.php#movies">Movies</a>
```

I need to toggle the state of the tab class `<ul class="nav panel-tabs">` **`-->`** `<li>` to active and remove it when the other links are clicked.

This is the panel with nav tabs:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="padpanel">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="pull-left">
        <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery" data-toggle="tab">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#movies" data-toggle="tab">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">Profile tab </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="gallery">Gallery tab </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="movies">Movies tab </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: onloading, `$("a[href$='"+location.hash.slice(1)+"']").click()` . then your section selection should be persisted upon reloading, as well as being linkable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get the page url #hash and select the Bootstrap tab...

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
if (hash) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
});
```

Code: http://codeply.com/go/RypzN2UXKF

Demo (select tab 2): http://codeply.com/render/RypzN2UXKF#tab2

Comment: I had to change the code to $('.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show'); to get it to work, was receiving a syntax error without the additional quotations.

Comment: This helped me with a project, but I have used vanilla JS like so: `if (document.location.hash) { document.querySelectorAll('ul.tabs li a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]')[0].click(); }`